# Python Code not working - why?

Tags: python, compilation

I am trying to learn Python and tried to run a code from

https://github.com/joelgrus/data-science-from-scratch/blob/master/code/statistics.py

However the code runs neither in Python nor in Ipython.
First it says, there is no module named `linear_algebra`, I am using is Anaconda3,  at least I don't know which equivalent would be the correct one.

Second the code does not accept the lines from "print" ~ around line 115, it always says SyntaxError: Invalid Syntax.

I've seen a similar question like 2-3 times when searching, but the answers could help me any further.....can someone explain, why the code isn't working or how I have to change it to use it?

Comment: you need to have all the files from https://github.com/joelgrus/data-science-from-scratch/tree/master/code and be running from that folder ... I believe that `code` folder  is python2 ... `code-pyton3` is python3

Comment: Have you installed linear_algebra package `conda install PACKAGENAME`?  If you are getting an error on the print message I would guess you have python 3 installed and the code you're trying to run is written for python 2.  Try `python -V` from the console to see.

Comment: @Jordan ah i just saw that u answered....this would have been it. 
The code is really python2, but after installing his own modules it works for the moment.

Answer (score 2):

You say you are using Anaconda3, which uses Python 3. However, several aspects of the code you link to make it clear that code is meant for Python 2. (The statement `from __future__ import division`, the print statements without parentheses, etc.)

So install Anaconda2 or some other distribution of Python 2, install the linear_algebra module, and try again.

Comment: This is a good answer. You can also rectify all of the python2 changes by hand (i.e. remove `from __future__ import division` and change all print commands), then implement your own sum_of_squares and dot methods with the same behavior as those from the linear_algebra library

Comment: Okay, that's a possible explanation and it's not downward compatible....thank you for your answer.

Comment: I installed Python 2.7, but it not working there either....it doesn't even know the modules. Can't solve it.

Comment: solved it...it was a modul created by the developer himself and has to be installed to the other scripts....ok that took long.  But thanks.